# Regex: how to get words, spaces and punctuation from string

Tags: c#, regex, sentence

Basically I want to iterate through all sentence, for example:

```
string sentence = "How was your day - Andrew, Jane?";
string[] separated = SeparateSentence(sentence);
```

`separated` output is following:

> [1] = "How"
>
> [2] = " "
>
> [3] = "was"
>
> [4] = " "
>
> [5] = "your"
>
> [6] = " "
>
> [7] = "day"
>
> [8] = " "
>
> [9] = "-"
>
> [10] = " "
>
> [11] = "Andrew"
>
> [12] = ","
>
> [13] = " "
>
> [14] = "Jane"
>
> [15] = "?"

As of currently I can only grab words, using `"\w(?<!\d)[\w'-]*"` Regex.
How to separate sentence into smaller parts, according to output example?

**Edit:** The string doesn't have any of the following:

- i.e.
- solid-form
- 8th, 1st, 2nd

Comment: Punctuation, such as `Andrew,` and `Jane?`, will be a problem. What if you have a string such as `7pm`. Would you like it to split into `7` and `pm` or no split at all?

Comment: there won't be words such as "8th", "7pm", "2nd", etc. So that's not a problem

Comment: That's a bad assumption, you should be ready for it as well.

Comment: I agree with you, however i currently have a text before my eyes and there aren't any "NumberWord" strings, also no "word-word", "i.e." etc

Comment: I was thinking about grabbing word positions, then grabbing punctuation positions, then spaces positions. And as a final step merging all 3 arrays into 1, based on positions of elements... In theory that should work, but the approach is too massive..

Comment: Look up Natural Language Tokenization...There's a lot of solutions for things like this...NLTK in Python is one solution.  There exist solutions in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
        string pattern = @"^(\s+|\d+|\w+|[^\d\s\w])+$";
        string input = "How was your 7 day - Andrew, Jane?";

        List<string> words = new List<string>();

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        if (regex.IsMatch(input))
        {
            Match match = regex.Match(input);

            foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[1].Captures)
                words.Add(capture.Value);
        }
```

Comment: it worked! thanks. Much simpler than "lexer" approach that I was going to use

Comment: Be aware that this solution will split `7pm` into `7` and `pm`

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this? It's tailored to your test case, but if you add punctuation this might be what you're looking for.

```
(\w+|[,-?])
```

EDIT: Ah, to steal from Andre's response, this is what I was envisioning:

```
string pattern = @"(\w+|[,-?])";
string input = "How was your 7 day - Andrew, Jane?";

List<string> words = new List<string>();

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

if (regex.IsMatch(input))
{
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);

    foreach (Match m in matches)
        words.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you implement a simple lexer (If such a thing exists) that will read the sentence one character at a time and generate the output you are looking for. Although not the simplest solution, it has the advantage of being scalable in case your use cases get more complicated as @AndreCalil suggested.

Comment: I think I understand what you are talking about. That might work well in my case. I'll be implementing this solutions if that's the best one ;)